# Using browserify with npm jQuery and non-npm plugins

Tags: jquery, node.js, browserify, browserify-shim

I am using [browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) to bundle front-end code. It's been great so far, but I've been having difficulty  mixing npm and non npm packages. For example, using the npm version of jQuery with non CJS versions of jQuery plugins.

My current solution is to use the `browser` key in `package.json` to point to jQuery's dist, and then use [`browserify-shim`](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim) to add it as a dependency of the plugins.

Is there a cleaner way to do this than what I currently have?

**Edit:** I'm currently trying to use npm and `package.json` to manage *all* my dependencies, so I don't want to use bower on this project. Call me crazy : )

**Package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.0",
    "browserify": "latest",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.5.0",
    "jquery-waypoints": "git@github.com:imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints.git",
    "jquery-validation": "git://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation"
  },
  "browser": {
    "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "jquery-waypoints": "./node_modules/jquery-waypoints/waypoints.js",
    "jquery-validate": "./node_modules/jquery-validation/build/release.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$",
    "jquery-waypoints": {
      "depends": [
        "jquery"
      ]
    },
    "jquery-validate": {
      "depends": [
        "jquery"
      ]
    }
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm tackling the same issue currently. Does aliasing `jquery` with `./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js` create a duplicate copy of jQuery in your final bundle? Or, what isn't working with that `package.json`?

Comment: @MichaelMartin-Smucker It's working fine (no duplicate `jquery`) but I don't like having to configure things manually via the shim config — I'm lazy :). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That question answered my question. I couldn't get jquery.mmenu to work, but your code showed me how. +1 for showing working code in a question :)

Comment: @NickTomlin I know this is an old question but does that code work as you have it? Or is the issue that your jQuery plugins don't work like that?

Comment: @YPCrumble the code works as is. I just want a cleaner way to do it :)

Comment: @NickTomlin the only way I can see is that your `browser` directive likely isn't necessary. Other than that it's the right code.

Answer (score 1):

I would do as follows:

1. Use [debowerify](https://github.com/eugeneware/debowerify) to include libraries available in bower, in your case will be, jquery-waypoints, jquery-validation
2. Use the jquery which comes in npm package, which is available here https://github.com/jquery/jquery

As such, I would also remove browserify-shim for the time being.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to go the npm only route at the moment, so i'd like to avoid using bower. I've updated my question to clarify.

Comment: I tried the way suggested and no luck with jquery-mobile. Debowerify brought in the package from bower but deamdify didn't know how to build it out of a amd module . It got unexpected token errors. Hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

The `browser` directive is just an alias to specify what you want when you write `jquery`. The *default* for `jquery` is the path in `node_modules`, so your line:

```
"jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
```

...is redundant and you could remove it, because when you write `"depends": ["jquery"]` in your Browserify Shim config, `jquery` already points to `./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js` without that line in your `browser` key. In fact, you could probably remove the `browser` directive entirely, you'd have to check the config in those jQuery plugins' `package.json` files but most likely they're already aliased as you have them, without the `browser` override.

Otherwise I don't think there is a cleaner way to implement this. Like you said you need to use Browserify Shim to shim those non-CJS jQuery plugins and you're doing it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing defining the dependencies correctly I believe (e.g. set "$" to your jquery declaration):

```
"plugin": {
  "exports": "plugin",
  "depends": [
    "jquery:$"
  ]
},...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i'm not quite sure what you mean? Could you elaborate and give a little more context to your snippet?

Comment: Erk. Stumbled across your question while looking for another solution so read too quickly. Just re-read your question and noticed that you actually have it working, but don't like the manual fiddling via browserify-shim (I had assumed that it wasn't working, potentially because you hadn't specified fully what to assign to $/jQuery in your plugin. Seeing as how you have it working, you're in the same boat as me: "argh, another jQuery plugin that I've got to make browserify-friendly." Unfortunately, there's no other way that I've found short of using a different package manager.

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense. Glad to know someone else feels my pain. Please update if you find a better way :)