# Where is jquery getting required from? - browserify - browserify-shim

Tags: browserify, browserify-shim

I am building a project with `broweserify`, `jquery` and `jquery-ui`.  All libs were pulled down with `npm`.  Here is how I am using my `browserify-shim` to pull in `jquery' and 'jquery-ui`:

```
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [ "browserify-shim" ]
  },
  "browser": {
    "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "jquery-ui": "./node_modules/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$"
  }
```

Everything works like it should, but I look at `jquery-ui.js` and the first line of code is

```
var jQuery = require('jquery');
```

How is this line of code being resolved?  When I put a `debugger`statement after this, `jquery` is always resolved.  I even changed the name of `jquery` in my shim and the it still resolved.  How is that happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: your `package.json` dependencies

**Long answer**: I'm also using those npm modules. That `jquery-ui` package seems to have been retooled to `require` its internal dependencies. As you note, the first line of the `jquery-ui` `core.js` is: `var jQuery = require('jquery');` which looks for a module called `jquery` in the project's npm dependencies. That's handled by something like what I have in my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.1.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.10.5",
}
```

in addition to the `browserify` parts:

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [ "browserify-shim" ]
},
"browser": {
    "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "jq-ui": "./node_modules/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$",
    "jq-ui": {
        "exports": "jq-ui",
        "depends": [ "jquery:jQuery" ]
    },
}
```

What I haven't figured out is whether we can use the jQuery UI components in our other client-side scripts.

See also:
* [Using Browserify with jquery and non-npm plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24186219/using-browserify-with-npm-jquery-and-non-npm-plugins?rq=1)
* [Using Browserify with jQuery plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707406/using-browserify-with-jquery-plugins?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you installed jquery and jquery-ui with npm, then I suspect they're somewhere in the rest of your dependencies. In that case, you're actually not using the "browser" "jquery" property, but instead letting browserify use it's non-shimmed "require" process.

Is "jquery" in your "dependencies" list? What happens if you delete that "browser" "jquery" line entirely?